# How to get the id attribute of a dynamically-generated element?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

How can I get the `id` attribute of a dynamically generated element when you don't know it's `id`? I am wanting to setup some `eventListener`s for about 2000 Checkbox's on a page.

I know I could call a function from within the element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{databaseResult.Value}" onclick="someFunction(this)" />
```

But I'm not allowed to use JavaScript, or references to it in my HTML. Pure JavaScript (or a language that compiles to it) is my only option.

The code I already have for some elements where I **do** know the `id`, is:

```
var tb = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tbox");

if(tb.addEventListener("", function (e) {
    sayHello(tb.value);
}, false));
```

Comment: Do you know its position in the DOM relative to an element you do know the ID of?

Comment: If all you want is to just select the 2000 boxes to bind the event, you could use  `$('[type=checkbox]')` which would select all the 2000 boxes.
Refer: http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Comment: Bind your event handlers to a parent element and use `event.target||event.srcElement`. With 2000 checkboxes surely delegated event handling is a nicer way to go.

Comment: I do know that it is inside *a* Grid control, but I do not know which one it is in.

Comment: @keithxm23: Yeah, in an ideal world I would be allowed to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a single listener on an ancestor element, say the body, and listen for events on that, e.g.:

```
<body onclick="handleClick(event);" ...>
```

and the function is:

```
function handleClick(evt) {
  var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

  if (el && el.type == 'checkbox') {
    alert(el.id);
  }
}
```

Of course you can add the listener dynamically, I've used inline for convenience.

#### Edit

To attach the listener dynamically, use an `addEvent` function to cope with IE and W3C event models:

```
function addEvent(el, evt, fn) {

  // W3C event model
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);

  // IE event model
  // Set this and pass event as first parameter
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on' + evt, (function(el, fn) {
        return function() {fn.call(el, window.event);};
      })(el, fn)
    );
  }

  // Prevent circular reference
  el = null;
}
```

And call it as:

```
window.onload = function() {
  addEvent(document.body, 'click', handleClick);
}
```

Comment: Hum... So, a listener on the body of the document will return whatever child element that triggered the event?

Comment: No, the listener passes the related `event` object, which has a `target` property (W3C event model) or `srcElement` property (IE event model) that references the element on which the event was dispatched.

Comment: This solution works great. I'd just like to add, for TypeScript users, if you're getting red squiglies, changing `addEvent(el` to `addEvent(el: any` gets rid of them. :-)